# How would I achieve this in opencv with an affine transform?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I was wondering how I would replicate what is being done in this image:
[image]

To break it down:

1. Get facial landmarks using dlib (green dots)
2. Rotate the image so that the eyes are horizontal
3. Find the midpoint of the face by averaging the left most and right most landmarks (blue dot) and center the image on the x-axis
4. Fix the position along the y-axis by by placing the eye center 45% from the top of the image, and the mouth center 25% from the image

Right now this is what I have:
[image]

I am kind of stuck on step 3, which I think can be done by an affine transform? But I'm completely stumped on step 4, I have no idea how I would achieve it.

Please tell me if you need me to provide the code!

EDIT: So after look at @Gal Dreiman's answer I was able to center the face perfectly so that the blue dot in the the center of my image.

[image]

Although when I implemented the second part of his answer I end up getting something like this:

[image]

I see that the points have been transformed to the right places, but it's not the outcome that I had desired as it is sheered quite dramatically. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

After switching the x, y coordinates for the center points around, this is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As I see you section 3, the easiest way to do that is by:

1. Find the faces in the image:

   ```
   faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
       gray,
       scaleFactor=1.1,
       minNeighbors=5,
       minSize=(30, 30),
       flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
   )
   ```
2. For each face calculate the midpoint:

   ```
   for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
       mid_x = x + int(w/2)
       mid_y = y + int(h/2)
   ```
3. Affine transform the image to center the blue dot you already calculated:

   ```
   height, width = img.shape
   x_dot = ...
   y_dot = ...

   dx_dot = int(width/2) - x_dot
   dy_dot = int(height/2) - y_dot

   M = np.float32([[1,0,dx_dot],[0,1,dy_dot]])
   dst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
   ```

Hope it was helpful.

**Edit:**

Regarding section 4:
In order to stretch (resize) the image, all you have to do is to perform an affine transform. To find the transformation matrix, we need three points from input image and their corresponding locations in output image.

```
    p_1 = [eyes_x, eye_y]
    p_2 = [int(width/2),int(height/2)] # default: center of the image
    p_3 = [mouth_x, mouth_y]

    target_p_1 = [eyes_x, int(eye_y * 0.45)]
    target_p_2 = [int(width/2),int(height/2)] # don't want to change
    target_p_3 = [mouth_x, int(mouth_y * 0.75)]

    pts1 = np.float32([p_1,p_2,p_3])
    pts2 = np.float32([target_p_1,target_p_2,target_p_3])

    M = cv2.getAffineTransform(pts1,pts2)

    output = cv2.warpAffine(image,M,(height,width))
```

To clear things out:

1. `eye_x` / `eye_y` is the location of the eye center.
2. The same applies on `mouth_x` / `mouth_y`, for mouth center.
3. `target_p_1/2/3` are the target points.

**Edit 2:** 
I see you are in trouble, I hope this time my suggestion will work for you:

There is another approach I can think of. you can perform sort of "crop" to the image by pointing on 4 points, lets define them as the 4 points which wrap the face, and change the image perspective according to their new position:

```
up_left = [x,y]
up_right = [...]
down_left = [...]
down_right = [...]

pts1 = np.float32([up_left,up_right,down_left,down_right])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))
```

So all you have to do is to define those 4 points. My suggestion, calculate the conture around the face (which you already did) and after that add `delta_x` and `delta_y` (or subtract) to the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks that centered my image! Do you have any ideas regarding step 4? How would I scale my image so that the face and mouth are in the right positions?

Comment: Thank you kind sir!

Comment: `@Gal Dreimand` would you mind looking at my updated question, I've successfully centered the face but resizing the shape is not going as expected.

Comment: Added a bounty if you're still interested :)

Comment: sorry for delay. I see in your update that according to your source points, the target points are in correct: you want to change only y axis: so why your center point has changed (probably instead of the first point)?

Comment: The first point is the center point, I do not want to change that point as I want it to stay as the center of the image.

Comment: I have a feeling that you switched x and y in each point. can you try [X,Y] (instead of [Y,X], i.e., the middle point suppose to be [281,231])?

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't as the middle point is supposed to be left of the center points for the mouth and the eyes. This is because the center point of the face is calculated as the average of the left most landmark and the right most landmark. As the face isn't straight, the center point isn't at the same place as the eyes and mouth center.

Comment: Just tried it and it sheared the image so much that it nearly became a line.

Comment: added another example for you. see "Edit 2"

Comment: Interesting question; did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope... didn't figure it out

Comment: Just a quick FYI, at work I've developed a project that could help you get this right. The face alignment part was mostly developed around procrustes analysis as explained by Matthew Earl https://matthewearl.github.io/2015/07/28/switching-eds-with-python/.